# overview of DLR?

Tags: language-design, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm looking for a high level overview of how one goes from an AST to working code via the DLR, does anyone have (a link for) something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a good 3 part tutorial about building a basic language from the parsing to the actual tree construction to the dlr mapping.

http://www.bitwisemag.com/2/DLR-Build-Your-Own-Language

All the current DLR specs and documents are located here:

http://dlr.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Docs%20and%20specs&referringTitle=Documentation

This tutorial is the one that I used to learn the DLR:

http://www.dotnetguru.org/us/dlrus/DLR2.htm

It builds a custom version of javascript on the DLR.

And if all else fails you can look here:
http://myjscript.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/changeset/view/8678?projectName=MyJScript#109043

to see the actual parser implementation, though I would probably recommend using Antlr as your parser.  That's what I use, though I've got a fair bit of Antlr experience:)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link that maybe helps: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/astdlrtest.aspx